# Get Friendly Name of claims from Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, wif, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am getting claims Type in identity like [this](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/AdLogon).

I just want the friendly name "**AdLogon**" as my claim type.
I know we can do it by manipulating strings but is there any standard way to do this.?

Answer (score 0):

The normal claims rule is of the form e.g.:

c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"), query = ";mail;{0}", param = c.Value);

Yours would like something like:

c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/AdLogon"), query = ";[some attribute];{0}", param = c.Value);

To get just "AdLogon", use:

c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("AdLogon"), query = ";[some attribute];{0}", param = c.Value);

Comment: I am authenticating it from a federation server using WIF ,so it is automatically populating claims Type=[link]http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/AdLogon format but I just want Type ="AdLogon".

Comment: I was talking about the claims rules in ADFS - or are you using something else?